# Using Tkinter and OOP to create transition frames in different classes (Python)

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, scope

I am creating frames for my project and so far I have it where it goes from the home page to the main page when the button is clicked. The problem I am facing is when I try to go from the home page to the log page where I am faced with an issue of calling the show_frame() function (located in MainApplication) in class MainPage.

How would I go about using arguments in MainPage so I can move from main page to log page?

```
class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # initialize frames
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage, MainPage, LogPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # show home page frame first
        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont): # <-- FUNCTION HERE
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        continue_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter program", width=15,
                                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage)) # <-- works here
        continue_button.pack()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def success_actions(self):
        self.run_script_button["text"] = "View log"
        self.run_script_button.configure(
                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LogPage)) # <-- want to use here

class LogPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only in **HomePage** because you made it inside the `__init__()` method but in the **MainPage** you need it outside.
To solve this try setting controller as an instance variable:

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def success_actions(self):
        self.run_script_button["text"] = "View log"
        self.run_script_button.configure(
            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(LogPage))
```

Comment: It is better to have some explanations on what you have done to address OP issue.  Also your code has indentation issue.